# How to automate a sequence of M-x options?

Tags: emacs

I'll give a clear example. I frequently have to start an nrepl session on a device connected to my computer, and I use the following sequence of commands:

```
1. M-x nrepl
2. host: <I write the hostname here>
3. port: <I write the port here>
```

How can I bind this sequence into one command I can type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>f1 f</kbd> `nrepl`:

```
nrepl is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
`nrepl.el'.

(nrepl HOST PORT)

Connect nrepl to HOST and PORT.
```

Hence `(nrepl "0.0.0.0" "3000")` is probably the kind of thing you want.
I don't have use for it, since I just use `nrepl-jack-in`, or since recently
`cider-jack-in`.

Comment: this is really n00bish (I am not an emacs poweruser yet), but how do I run that function?

Comment: I also use nrepl-jack-in normally, but this is for doing android development

Comment: How do you run it? Either `M-: (nrepl "0.0.0.0" "3000")` or define a command that does it: `(defun foo () (interactive) (nrepl "0.0.0.0" "3000"))`, and then `M-x foo`.